# Is $\int\,dx=\int1\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm just wondering if $\int\,\mathrm dx$ can be written instead of $\int1\,\mathrm dx$.

This sometimes comes up while finding the integrating factor of a suitable differential equation, when the coefficient of $y$ is $1$ and the integrating factor is thus $e^{\int1\,\mathrm dx}=e^x$.

Comment: Yes, usually the $1$ is omitted, just like when we write $x$ instead of $1x$.

Comment: @user2825632 Thank you very much. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, usually the $1$ is omitted, just like when we write $x$ instead of $1x$.